# Failed to insert a row

Tags: php, mysql, insert

What is wrong with following code? Without smiley function it works and with **$tz = smiley($this->text);** doesn't.

I tried to put to display the errors but .. mhmm doesn't works.. 0 errors

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);


<?php
class ChatLine extends ChatBase
{
    protected $text = '', $author = '', $gravatar = '';
    public function save()
    {
        $tz = smiley($this->text);

        DB::query("
            INSERT INTO webchat_lines (author, gravatar, text)
            VALUES (
                '".DB::esc($this->author)."',
                '".DB::esc($this->gravatar)."',
                '".$tz."'
        )");

        // Returns the MySQLi object of the DB class
        return DB::getMySQLiObject();
    }

    public function smiley($text)
    {
        $privatesmilies = array(
          ":)" => "smile1.gif",
          ";)" => "wink.gif"
        );

        reset($privatesmilies);
        while (list($code, $url) = each($privatesmilies))
            $text = str_replace($code, "<img src=http://127.0.0.1/chat/img/$url align=absmiddle/>", $text);

        return $text;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try $tz = $this->smiley($this->text);

Comment: What's wrong with this apple no-one can see? _Please_ give some explanation as to **why** it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You've enabled error reporting by placing the appropriate function calls... outside a PHP code block! Instead of this:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

<?php
// ...
?>
```

... do this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// ... 
?>
```

Then PHP will tell you that there isn't a function called `smiley()`. There is, however, a class method: `$this->smiley()`.

Comment: When I posted the whole code I erased the reporting errors.